# Concatenate two text files using command line (windows) in a Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I am writing a BATCH Script using windows command prompt commands where I need to merge two text files in one of the source files:
Input files:

```
ADAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt
AEDAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt
```

Output files:

```
ADAT_DZ01_20220320_104155.txt
```

(Result of merging the 2 input files)

**PS/** the files name changes with every extraction from the app :

```
ADAT_DZ01_[the changing part].txt
AEDAT_DZ01_[the changing part].txt
```

`copy /b ADAT*.txt + AEDAT*.txt AEDAT*.txt` didn't work.
`more ADAT*.txt AEDAT*.txt >> ADAT*.txt` also didn't work

Comment: Is there ever only one `ADAT*` and one `AEDAT*` file in your folder? If not - how to identify the correct ones? Do they *always* come as a pair?

Comment: The name of your input file is the same as the output filename. Your attempts are designed to output to `AEDAT` and `ADAT` respectively. Are you aware that if you output to a file defined as an input, then re-running the code will append the second file again, and the next time, there will be yet another copy generated?

Comment: @stephan in fact ADAT* & AEDAT* are files loaded from executing a job in some software (The reason why there's a changing part in filenames) that need to be merged in ADAT* then sent to some server using FTP. So yes There's only one of each and Yes they come as a pair.

Comment: @MAGOO Yes that's the point, it has to be like this since I need to respect the name form as it is in the target server that i will put the merged file in. once the file is loaded in the target server, the file will be deleted and the process restart again with a new ADAT* & AEDAT* files again, so there's no issue in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... As I understand it, you want to *append* each `AEDAT_...` file to the end of the corresponding `ADAT_...` one (you are not clear about what "merge two files" means). If so, this is a solution:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B AEDAT_*.txt') do (
   (echo/
    type "%%a_%%b") >> "ADAT_%%b"
   del "%%a_%%b"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much your solution works, there's only one thing that needs to be adjusted. I need the content of the second file (AEDAT_*) to start from a new line which is not the case actually ( In this solution it's pasted in the last character of the content of ADAT_* file) .

Comment: Ready, mod done in the code...

Comment: As you see, you may insert anything you want before/after the appended file

Comment: I created a blank file named "void.txt" and did the following and it works:                @echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B AEDAT_*.txt') do (
   (
    type void.txt >> "ADAT_%%b" && type "%%a_%%b") >> "ADAT_%%b"
   del "%%a_%%b"
)                                                                                                                         Thank you for helping out !

Comment: Well, an `echo/` command is simpler than creating a blank file and then use `type void.txt` (besides, the purpose of the echo is evident whereas the void.txt file is not). If the type command is enclosed in those parens, it does not require its own `>> "ADAT_%%b"` redirection (that just makes the process more complicated). The `&&` is used in just a few specific cases; the `&` is simpler and just put each command in separate lines is even simpler... Perhaps you don't like simple things and prefer convoluted ones, like your change in the Best Answer selection **`:(`**

Answer (score 0):

This batch should do the trick, feel free to adapt.
Please read carefully comments within the source.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

REM Defining base prefix for both files.
set F1_PREFIX=ADAT_DZ01_
set F2_PREFIX=AEDAT_DZ01_

pushd %~dp0
REM Searching all "F1" files. No need to search for "F2".
for %%A in (%F1_PREFIX%*.txt) do (
    echo Found file: %%A
    REM Splitting the file name to get the variable part.
    for /f "tokens=2,* delims=_" %%B in ("%%A") do (
        echo    Found suffix: %%C
        REM Build second file name.
        set second=!F2_PREFIX!%%C
        REM Second file exist? Need to merge.
        if exist !second! (
            echo    Merging %%A and !second! into %%A...
            REM Simply append content of 2nd file at end of 1st file.
            type !second!>>%%A
            REM Remove 2nd file, useless now, and we don't want to append it twice.
            del /s /q !second! > NUL 2>&1
        ) else (
            REM 2nd file does not exist? Already merged.
            echo    Already merged, skipping...
        )
        echo    Done.
    )
)
popd
goto :eof
```